# I am trying to display a QR code on button press, but the QR code does not show

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

> I am new to react JS, I am trying to display a QR code on button press, but the QR code does not show. This class is of the QR code

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {
  state = {
    text: 'http://facebook.github.io/react-native/',
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <QRCode
          value={this.state.text}
          size={1000}
          bgColor='black'
          fgColor='white'/>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
 const qr=new HelloWorld;
```

> then I have created an object of hello world and called it in the profile, when a button is pressed.

```
> const qr=new HelloWorld;
  const Profile = ({ navigation }) => {

    

    
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Vaccines</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => qr.render()} underlayColor="white">
          
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SinoVac</Text>
            
          </View>
         
        </TouchableHighlight>
 




      </View>

    );
    
    }
```

> In the output, the profile is displayed but when I press the button nothing appears, neither do I get any error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting method of rendering a class component. Theoretically, it might work, but since I've never seen it before, I'm not shocked that it doesn't.  It might do something if you write `const qr = new HelloWorld();` before calling the render method (note the parens at the end, which are missing in your code).  Even so, I would expect it to not behave as you want; you're calling `render()` within the onPress prop of a Touchable, which doesn't tell React where on the page to put it.

Even if it works somehow, I encourage you to use the standard method. Classes are usually rendered as any other JSX is: `<HelloWorld />`.  Not only is this less code (you don't have to instantiate your class in a variable before calling its render method), it will be easier for others to read, and use the React model.

One common method of showing and hiding components is to keep a state value that controls whether they are shown.  Your HelloWorld component is fine as written. I would change your Profile component to be something like the following:

```js
  const Profile = () => {
    const [showQr, setShowQr] = useState(false);
    return (  
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Vaccines</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setShowQr(!showQr)} underlayColor="white">
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SinoVac</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        {showQr && <HelloWorld />}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I don't know where you want the QR to render, but using this code, it will show up after the button. There's a new piece of local state, `showQr`, which the button now toggles between true and false.  When `showQr` is true, the HelloWorld component will be rendered.

Comment: how can I show this qr code as a pop up, more like an alert message?

Comment: That's a new question, but you could do it with the built-in Modal: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal, or build your own with position: 'absolute'

Comment: No problem.  If the solution worked for you, please mark it as accepted.  Good luck!